# ubuntu 14.04 stuck in login loop. Nothing seems to help

Tags: 12.04, command-line, login

just an hour ago, I installed some package which was supposed to solve the problem with dead keys. After that I restarted my laptop and could not log in because of infinite loop with the login page.
I can use the user account but what can I do from it?

I cannot access BIOS, booting from USB does not work. I tried to switch from GUI to the shell Str+Alt+F3 and login in using my superuser credentials but sudo is not recognized in the shell. This is the error message I got:

Command ´Sudo´ is available in /usr/bin/sudo
this command cound not be located because /usr/bin is not included in the PATH environment variable.
Sudo command not found.

Im begging for help.

Comment: I already saw the answer, nothing of that helped since I cannot use sudo command in the shell.

Comment: Have you tried executing `sudo` with the full path i.e. `/usr/bin/sudo somecommand`? Have you tried resetting your `PATH` variable from the Ctrl-Alt-F3 login?

Comment: thank you for the response. I had to admit that I switched to ubuntu from Windows 7 only today...had some working experience with ubuntu in the past but Im not a programmer after all. Im just a chemist. I would be grateful for your guidance here. I will try now full sudo path. Not sure I understand how to reset PATH, though?

Comment: looks like I found the root of the problem. ./profile. PATH="$PATH:/home/alex/mipav"
PATH="$PATH:/etc/fsl/5.0/fsl.sh"
". /etc/fsl/5.0/fsl.sh"
export DIALOG_SLEEP=4

Comment: How to roll back the changes made to the ./profile? Or can I correct the file from the shell?

Comment: You can reset the default system-wide `PATH` in the current session by re-sourcing the /etc/environment file i.e. `. /etc/environment` or `source /etc/environment`. After that you should be able to make any necessary edits to your `~/.profile` file

Comment: It was a very good lesson for me. I edited ./profile in the shell (path was not specified correctly) and after that Im able to log back in to my account again. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try booting from CD/DVD or network.
2. Instead of sudo, try `/usr/bin/sudo` or add PATH: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin`
3. Try booting into recovery mode: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode
4. There is an option in grub to boot into single user mode (as root), usualy it requires adding `single` to kernel options and updating grub, but I guess it can also be done in grub command line manually.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how `which sudo` helps in this situation - doesn't it just search exactly the same executable `PATH`?

Comment: You are 100% right.