# Ubuntu 14.04 login loop - Guest sessions does not work either

Tags: 14.04, xorg, lightdm, login-screen

I have been using Ubuntu 14.04 soon after it is released. Today I messed something up with the Chinese input ibus, and I don't know if this is the reason at all, but when I reboot using `sudo shutdown -r now`, I cannot pass the login. I entered the correct password, but then the screen just went black, and then the login screen comes up again!

I have searched quite a few solutions from others, but nothing is working for me.

I have read

- [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)
- [ubuntu 14.04 stuck in login loop. Nothing seems to help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517794/ubuntu-14-04-stuck-in-login-loop-nothing-seems-to-help)
- [Login screen loops unless you login as Guest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146137/login-screen-loops-unless-you-login-as-guest)
- [What represent .Xauthority file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300682/what-represent-xauthority-file)

I tried to look at `.xsession-error`, but that file is empty on my computer.

I tried the suggestion of changing the ownership of `.Xauthority`, but my .Xauthority is not root initially. I also tried to delete it  but that does not work either.

I did `sudo apt-get remove ibus-pinyin` in case it is the problem (but not likely).

I also tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm`, but it does not work either. I also tried `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, but I was not able to see the effect.

Also, I looked at `/var/crash`, and I saw a file `_usr_bin_xpad.1000.crash`, which seems to record the crash occured at the time that I first encountered thr login loop problem. Yet I cannot find further clue of how to solve it. At the bottom of that file, it suggested to update several packages if the crash still occurs. I did so but it does not work either. These packages are `krb5-locales`, `libgssapi-krb5-2`, `libk5crypto3`, `libkrb5-3`, `libkrb5support0`, `libprocps3`, `procps`

Can someone save me...I dont wanna switch back to Windows

Comment: Can you log into TTY1? You would have to press [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F1] and manually enter your username and password into the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the attention. Yea certainly. If I cannot login to TTY, I cannot have tried those stuffs I listed.

Comment: You could have done from within a live system...

Comment: Okay..But do you have any idea how to resolve this? I will really appreciate

Comment: Can you create a new user through TTY1 and then log into that graphically?

Comment: @ByteCommander Thanks. I tried that, but it does not work either. Also, the Guest session doesn't work as well. It just loops back to the login screen...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21121/discussion-between-zkytony-and-bytecommander).

Answer (score -1):

I solved a similar problem by erasing the file "/etc/shadow.lock". I tried this, because I had no chance to create new users... There is a second lock-file, named "passwd.lock". Only removing this file did not solve the problem.

Maybe this could work to escape from the guest-session loop. I will test this solution with other computers, when this error appears again.